# Div Positioning follows the other div

Tags: css, html, comments, positioning

Having a little problem with the comment part on the website i'm working on:

http://whybaguio.com/php/profile/businessprofile.php?id=103#

See how the ADD YOUR OWN FEEDBACK! div goes down together with the Facebook comment. I don't know how to not let it go down with the facebook comments.... Lol, I'm not really sure if I'm explaining my self right but I hope you guys get it...

I tried positioning it relative and absolute but it goes out of its parent div....

Please help me out, thank you!

Comment: Could you please post the actual code specific to the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is a problem with how to use `position:absolute;` What you need to do is change your code like this:

```
#feed {
background: white;
height: 280px;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 295px;
overflow-y: auto;
margin-left: -580px;
position: relative;/*this needs to have a position for .secondcomment to 'hook on' to*/
}

.secondcomment {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it right: place the "ADD YOUR OWN FEEDBACK" div before the "Facebook comment" div in your HTML code.

Your "ADD YOUR OWN FEEDBACK" div has a "float: right" property and blocks with "float" should go before non-floating blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `float: left;` property to `.fb-comment` class, and remove `margin-left` property from `.secondcomment` class.